# PowerShell backup folders with all files upload ftp

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, backup

I'm trying to upload a folder from my local computer to an FTP folder with all content (files of all types, subfolders). I try release script don't get error but when I try check FTP no files uploaded or folders.

```
$source = "E:\test"
$destination = "ftp://user:password@x.x.x.x/disk1/ftp/SRV/Tes"

$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient

$files = Get-ChildItem $source
$Today = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"

foreach ($file in $file)
{
    Write-Host "Uploading $file"
    $webclient.UploadFile("$destination/$file", $file.FullName)
} 

$webclient.Dispose()
```

After changing `foreach ($file in $file)` to `foreach ($file in $files)` I'm getting the following error:

```
Uploading afas
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred
during a WebClient request."
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scriptas kopijavimui.ps1:12 char:5
+ $webclient.UploadFile("$destianation/$file", $file.FullName)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException Uploading Image.bmp
```

Comment: `foreach ($file in $file)` should be `foreach ($file in $files)`

Comment: Catch the exception and check its inner exception. There will be more details for sure.

Comment: How that can be done ?

Comment: Did you look at a getting started guide [like that](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell) one?

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you need to provide additional information. Do not bury it in comments.